# Android camera background change using OpenCV or other libraries

Tags: opencv, android

I am building a camera application in android which should also render some dynamic content in the backgound(like sky filter) .I couldn't find any examples directly in openCV. Is there a direct way in openCV using which I can do this? If not are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to do such thing would be something like this:

- Implement a fragment that implements `CvCameraViewListener2`, and override the function `onCameraFrame` (if you need any help with that you can check any Android-OpenCV tutorial). At this function you should do two things:
- Use `BackgroundSubtractor` class to create a mask of the background of the image (binary image, using 1 to indicate if a pixel is part of the background and 0 if it's not). I have never tried it but rumors say it's a good algorithm, you can check its documention - https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html.
- Use the `Mat.setTo` method to copy any content you want to the input image, using the mask parameter to define which parts would be affected from the `setTo` method.